# Rails - Check if record has been updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to check whether a record has been updated/edited, and if it has, then it should display that is has been edited.

This is my if statement:

```
<% if comment.changed? %>
    <p id="comment-name"><%= comment.user.name %>(edited)</p>
<% else %>
    <p id="comment-name"><%= comment.user.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Although it isn't working. When a comment is updated, no `(edited)` text is showing. What do I need to put in the if statement to check whether the comment record has been updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `#changed?` is doing what you think it's doing.

> `#changed?` returns true if any attribute have unsaved changes, false
>   otherwise.

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changed-3F)

---

A record is edited if it's `updated_at` is different than `created_at` ( `updated_at` should be greater than `created_at` to be more precise).

```
<% if comment.updated_at != comment.created_at %>
    <p id="comment-name"><%= comment.user.name %>(edited)</p>
<% else %>
    <p id="comment-name"><%= comment.user.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much

Comment: @fox No problem :), I clarified my answer slightly on your use of `changed?`.

Comment: I think that option doesn't work propertly, it only is valid the first time you change the record, in previous changes the updated_at always will be different of created_at even if the record wasn't saved