# Update record if not updated in database using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-update

I need to save an object in the database only if this was not updated by others.
For example,

```
p = Person.find_by_id(1)
p.token = '83747'
```

Here, I would like to the object to be saved in the db only when this has not been updated in the database. Something like the query below.

`update persons set token='83747' where id=p.id and updated_at != p.updated`

I figured that I can use lock_version to achieve this. But, my need it to avoid updating this when running from cron job. Is there a way to achieve this using Active record. And there are callbacks on the model.

Just to clarify further, I am trying not to update the record in the database, if I have the stale copy of the record to avoid overwriting the changes made by someone else.

How can this be achieved without having to use lock_version and also ensuring that callbacks works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - Check if record has been updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731762/rails-check-if-record-has-been-updated)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `created_at` and `updated_at` default attributes (if this is sufficient enough in your case), by something like the following

```
p = Person.find_by(1)

# if has never been updated yet
if p.created_at != p.updated_at
  p.token = '83747'
  p.save
end
```